# Persist actions after button onclick() : JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the following initial structure:

```
PrimaryLabel: 'Drop-Down' [Add Button]
```

Once I click on the Add button, Another `Label: 'Drop-Down' [Add Button]` must be displayed :: That's the requirement. Maximum such lines? => 5

```
PrimaryLabel: 'Drop-Down' [Add Button]
Label: 'Drop-Down' [Add Button]
```

I've set all labels', Drop-downs' and Button' [other than primary] `display` property to `none`.

I've the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function add(currBtnId,nextDdId, nextBtnId, event){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(currBtnId, nextBtnId, nextDdId);
                document.getElementById(currBtnId).disabled = true;
                $('#'+nextBtnId).show();
                if (nextDdId!=null) {
                    $('#'+nextDdId).show();
                }
            }
        </script>
```

Here's how my button looks like:

```
<h:button type="button" value="ADD" class="add-btn" id="current-btn-id" onclick="add('current-btn-id', 'some-drop-down-id', 'next-btn-id', event)"/>
```

This is how it looks like after inspect-element:

```
<input id="add-btn1" type="button" onclick="add('add-btn1', 'reqpanel1', 'add-btn2', event); window.location.href='/project-name/page-name'; return false;" value="ADD" class="add-btn">
```

***Problem:***

After I click the Add button, the next label, drop-down and Add buttons show, but **only for a second**. It goes back to the initial state almost immediately.
What should I do now?

I think the problematic part is: `window.location.href='/project-name/page-name';`

How do I get rid of it? It reloads every time the button is clicked.

Comment: can you please add what you have done to a jsfiddle

Comment: Your page is probably submitting back to itself. Create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem using either a stacksnippet (icon above the editor with 2 angle brackets) or http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Jamiec Please check now, I've added more information.

Comment: You're redirecting the page when someone clicks the button - of course the DOM update will not be persisted! Something *must* be adding the `window.location....` bit. what is `<h:button`?

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, I found that out after I used the inspect element of the chrome browser. [<h: is for jsf HTML tags.] I'm not able to find out *what* is adding it though. Even after using `event.preventdefault()` and `return false` and `type=button`, the default nature of button, that is to reload does not go away.